# Bipartite vertex separator

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, co.combinatorics, approximation-algorithms

Are there any common approaches for finding a vertex separator in a bipartite graph $G = (V_1, V_2, E)$ where the selected vertices are constrained to come from one partition of the graph?

I have a large bipartite graph with $|V_1|$ = 40M and $|V_2|$ = 150K and want to remove vertices from $V_1$ to disconnect the graph.  Obviously, with a graph this large, I need a fairly efficient algorithm.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: one way is to connect each pair of neighbors $x,y\in N(v)\cap V_1$ for each vertex $v\in V_2$, and then find a minimum separator in the new graph.

Comment: A suggestion, but without theoretical backing: Pick a vertex or small set of vertices at random and run a breadth-first search starting there. Note that each "layer" (set of vertices at distance $d$ from the original vertex/set) either lies entirely within $V_1$ or within $V_2$, and furthermore each layer is a separating set (for the vertices before it in the BFS and the vertices after it). Pick the smallest layer that lies within $V_1$. Maybe repeat this a couple times with different initial vertices/sets.

Comment: Two more: (1) find a min cut and take all the $V_1$ vertices attached to it.  (2) Find a maximum matching, remove all the $V_1$ vertices in it (adding them to your separating set), and repeat on the remaining graph.